# RigidBody or Character Controller for Zero Gravity first person shooter

Tags: unity, physics, first-person-shooter

I am developing a single person, first-person shooter that takes place in space. I want to be able to simulate zero gravity. Should I use a Rigid-Body or a Character Controller?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Game Dev! Could you be more specific about this game of yours? The more details you give (like level design), the more accurate of an answer can be given!

Comment: @TheMattbat999 The game will be a fast-paced first-person shooter where you have fight off hordes of aliens through a zero-g environment. You can move around using a jetpack. The game is inspired by older shooters like doom and quake but will have much more verticality. The levels will be relatively short(5-10 minutes) and linear. I've just started developing the game and it's my first relatively large game.

Comment: please edit those details into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want free-floating Newtonian physics, that's exactly what a Rigidbody provides.

The CharacterController is for cases where you want to avoid dealing with physics directly, where you don't want to fight the physics engine to stop the character from feeling "slippery" or "floaty" or to give the movement more control and personality than a basic physics object.

But in your case, the "floatiness" of raw Newtonian physics is actually a feature, not a detriment.